# Que pasa si supero las notificaciones permitidas silenciosas en Background iOS Swift?

Tags: firebase, ios, swift, background, notification

Estoy manejando notificaciones silenciosas de data con Cloud Messaging de Firebase, pero de vez en cuando deja de recibir notificiones silenciosas en Background y solo en Foreground sin ninguna razón. Entonces no sé si hay limitaciones respecto a esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Está todo explicado en el [apartado *Regulación y escalamiento*](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=es#throttling-and-scaling) de la documentación.

Comment: @A.Cedano listo pero digamos si sigo recibiendo en foreground implicaría que pueda ser cosa de iOS, entonces refórmo mi pregunta respecto a esto que afirma Apple. "he number of background notifications allowed by the system depends on current conditions, but don’t try to send more than two or three per hour." A partir de esto que es sacado de https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app?language=objc, que pasa si supero mas de 3 notificaciones entra en una lista negra por un tiempo o ago parecido?

Comment: No lo sé, yo no desarrollo aún aplicaciones en Swift, no tengo ninguna experiencia en esa plataforma por lo que no sabría decirte. Si tienes una pregunta sobre las notificaciones en dispositivos iOS creo que es mejor que abras una nueva pregunta al respecto indicando lo que has investigado. La duda inicial planteada aquí era sobre si FCM tenía limitaciones. Creo que son dos cosas distintas. Quizá alguien con experiencia en programación iOS pueda responderte mejor.

Comment: Listo ty @A.Cedano, de todas maneras gracias por la info ya que también influye.